# Is there any limit to setTimeout?

Tags: javascript, node.js, v8

Specifically talking about (server side) V8, and assuming I'm not concerned about accuracy because I can detect and compensate for it, could I *literally* set up thousands of relatively simple timeouts several seconds apart from each other using setTimeout without facing any other limit other than RAM? Is there any catch I should be aware of if I were to use a system where there may be thousands of scheduled timeouts at any given time?

For the record I've read John's Resig excellent article on [How Javascript Timers work](http://ejohn.org/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/) so no need to point out anything that's already covered there :) I'm aware node.js is single threaded, timers can block other timers if they take too long, etc.

PS: I'm strictly trying to understand how viable is what I describe, no need to point out "there's surely a better way to do what you intend to do!".

Comment: there's guaranteed a better way to do what you intend to do!

Comment: Setting up a few million timeouts is just a `for` loop away. Try it and tell us instead. ;)

Comment: @Jon I tried this because I was also wondering and I believe it was not that expensive...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The only real world limit you may come up against is the amount of memory available to node. Use the following code to test. I successfully ran the example below using oneMillion and int32Max. When using int64Max, I received the following error from node. I'm using 64bit windows with 4gb of RAM.

```
FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_2 Allocation failed - process out of memory
```

Node code to test:

```
var util = require('util');
var int64Max = 9007199254740992; 
var int32Max = 2147483647;
var oneMillion = 1000000;
var tenThousand = 10000;
var counter = 0;

//Exchange the limiter with one of the above vars to test.
for (var i = 0; i < oneMillion; i++){   
     setTimeout(log, 1);
     //Required as the timeout/callback method will not be called until the loop ends due 
     //to node/js being single threaded.
     util.log('loop:' + i);
}

function log(){
     util.log('callback: ' + counter++);
}
```

Comment: Javascript numbers have 53 bits of mantissa, so once it reaches around 2^53, the increment no longer works, it rounds off to the same number without causing any change. Doubt it? Try `Math.pow(2,53)` and `Math.pow(2,53)+1` in a debugger console. Why is `int64Max` mentioned at all?

Comment: I haven't a `process out of memory`, but when I do a timeout higher than `2147483647`, the callback function is directly launch ! I'm running it inside a docker container btw

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how node operates, but if you create MAXINT+1 timers without letting them run, you risk an integer overflow.

Answer (score 2):

I have come to find, through my own experience, that a single `setTimeout` has a maximum delay of 2500000000 milliseconds (about 29 days). Anything beyond that delay, and it actions the code/function straight away - as if the delay were 0 milliseconds.

Comment: I have later found out this only happens with node.js applications